# RestKit: making network calls when app is running in the background

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have been using the following procedure to make the network calls when my app is in background:

```
RKRequest *rkRequest = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/..." params:paramsJsonified delegate:self];

[rkRequest setUserData:@"..."];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive){
    [rkRequest sendAsynchronously];
}
```

At the same time a background task is running as well. This has been mostly working so far, till recently I saw that I'm receiving duplicate calls on the server once in a while.

Can some one please explain the right approach to using RestKit when app is in the background and point out what I'm doing wrong here.